# How to change a label from another class? c# windows forms visual studio

Tags: c#, forms, class, methods, label

I know there are a lot of threads talking about this and believe me I've seen all of them, but I think I'm a little slow and cant figure out how to do this so here is the thing!
I have one form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adi mYadi= new adi();
        adi.paso(); 
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void l8u(string l )
    {
       label8.Text = l; 
    }
}
```

The `l8u` method is supposed to change the text in `label8`, so it can't be static because `label8` isn't static (is public) and I have this other class

```
public class adi :instrucion
{
    private  int paso;
    private  int registroD;
    private  int registroO; 
    private  int valor;
    private  int vsin; 

    public adi()
    {
        paso = 1;
    }

    public  void setRD(int i){
        registroD = i; 
    }

    public  void setR0(int i)
    {
        registroO = i;
    }
    public void setV(int i)
    {
        valor = i;
    }

    public  int getRD()
    {
        return registroD ;
    }

    public  int getR0()
    {
        return registroO;
    }

    public int getVf()
    {
        return vsin;
    }

    public void paso(){
         //in this method I need change the value of label8
    }  
}
```

The method paso is the one in charge of changing the value of `label8` but I just can't do it! I've tried many different ways for example doing something like

```
public void paso()
{
    Form1.l8u();
}
```

But that's not possible since `Form1` is just the name of the class and l8u is not and static method, also tried setting `label8` as public static but visual studio didn't like that and whenever I used a new control in the form VS change the public static for just public.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: You need to pass in an instance of Form1 to the instance of your `adi` class. It also wouldn't hurt for you to have a better acceptance %.

Comment: I have not idea what the acceptance % does.....

Comment: Accept some answers from some of your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simply change your label' s Modifier prperty to internal or public and then call your form and change your label text directly..

i.e.

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(); // Form 2 contains label8 and calling in a method (i.e.buttonclick) of form1

if (List<WhoLovesMe>.Count > 0)
{
   frm.Label8.Text = "Someone Loves Me :)";
}
else
{
   frm.Label8.Text = "Noone Loves Me :(";
}
```

Comment: but it creates a new form and change the value of Label8 in this new form, correct? Because I have tried that before (create a new instance of form1 and change the value of label8) but it doesn't do anything

Comment: No. When you call in a seperate form the form which you call only initialized (ready to use it) if you set its property to internal / protected internal or public.. But if its modifier sets to private then yes a new form from scratch initializes..

and if your form (which you want to change it's some of control's property ) already showed on screen you need to invalidate it to see the changes..

all event based settings use this method.. calls the new instance of the form and set properties and show / validate

Comment: Well this way isn't working for me :( but i just found I just found a little code that do the trick is this:                                            `Label lb = (Label) Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls.Find("label8", false).FirstOrDefault();
lb.Text = "Form2";)` What do you think about this? Is it a good idea use this?

Comment: yes..this is good for forms which already shown.. but if you need to think even so small performance gains then you can filter it like this :

Application.OpenForms["Form2"].Controls.OfType<Label>().First(x=> x.Name == "Label8");

if you use firstordefault() and query can't get a positive result it will throw an exception which you cannot control and app will stop..

but with this you can control the exception something like

if( lb.Name == null)
{
MessageBox.Show("there is no control named which you search");
}

Comment: Just because the language allows you to do something, doesn't mean that is a very good solution. This is a *very* hacked way to do what he wants.

Comment: @debracey exactly you are right.. But as you know better than me the first rules of best practices in coding, 

to going on a more secure, faster, and more simple way which gives you what you need without error..

sometimes to go in most secure way (distinctly go ahead on rules) cannot be a best choice..

then it would be like : you are on a highway, after some road highway will turn to a small stone road.. if you need to arrive your target-place and small road won't damage your car

then will you prefer to wait to complete the highway construction?? 

or continue from small road and goal?

Comment: @debracey as an example.. right now im working on a project which is my own..

in that project i need a little bit complicated situation control..8 different situations in 14 situations and these are in 2 main situations..

for that the rules say : use an interface, a class, a sublass, attributes, and check all situations from there..

can you guess if i do them how much i lose time and stack from ram-pool ? for a checking in **only 1 form**

i just use 2 short values and control all them in a method..

almost the same..its dirty but i gain from ram using and coding time..

Answer (score 3):

Changing the label in that manner is not a good idea and violates some programming paradigms. Generally, the underlying business logic classes are not supposed to directly manipulate the UI.

The form contains an instance of adi. So, short of passing the form's instance (ie. `this`) to the `adi` constructor (or to the paso method), you're kinda sunk.

Better to use some kind of event that adi can fire when it needs `Form1` to change its display.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 2 years ago but couldnt you just do this

```
public static void function(label l)
  {
    l.Text = "Changed text"
  }
```

and then in the Form do

```
private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    function(label);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for answer, but i finally found out how to change the label of form1 from another class.

usually Form1.Designer.cs looks like this:

```
            this.label6.AutoSize = true;
        this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(59, 174);
        this.label6.Name = "label6";
        this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 13);
        this.label6.TabIndex = 16;
        this.label6.Text = "Output String:";
```

Form1.Designer.cs Should look like this so you can call it on another class:

```
        label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

            label8.AutoSize = true;
        label8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(219, 26);
        label8.Name = "label8";
        label8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        label8.TabIndex = 25;
        label8.Text = "label8";  

         // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.Controls.Add(label8);
```

some "this." text except the part on "this.Controls.Add" in label8 at Form1.Designer.cs

And you should call it from the another class like this:

```
WindowsFormsApplication999.Form1.label8.Text = "your text here."; //This should modify label8.Text.
```

edit:

You should also modify this in Form1.Designer.cs

```
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label8;
```

into this:

```
        public static System.Windows.Forms.Label label8;
```