# Objects from another Class In C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to 2 Classes (1 Form class)
in form class, I call Another Class void. It works 
And I want do thigs with labels and textboxes (in second class script)
I saw this [How to change a label from another class? c# windows forms visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770920/how-to-change-a-label-from-another-class-c-sharp-windows-forms-visual-studio)
and my code :

```
`private new void Enter(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
            {
                Commands.OnCommand();`
```

other class :

```
public static void OnCommand()
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        if (frm.code.Text.Contains("end") && frm.code.TextLength == 4)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Close?", "Close window?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                frm.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                frm.output.Text = (frm.output.Text + "\nClosing closed").ToString();
                frm.code.Clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
            frm.output.Text = (frm.output.Text + "\nI don't understand ... ").ToString();
            frm.code.Clear();
        } /**/
```

it only shows message box on end
....I think error is in declaring form1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a reference to the original Form, not create a new instance of it:

```
private new void Enter(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
    {
        Commands.OnCommand(this);



public static void OnCommand(Form1 frm)
{
    if (frm.code.Text.Contains("end") && frm.code.TextLength == 4)
    {
```

That being said, I'd consider it poor practice to send a reference to the entire Form into the other method. Instead, try to restructure it so that you pass in just those values the method needs (like `code.Text`), and have it return the values that the Form needs to display.

```
private new void Enter(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
    {
        string message = Commands.OnCommand(code.Text);

        if (message == "")
        {
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            frm.output.Text = frm.output.Text + message;
            frm.code.Clear();
        }



public static void OnCommand(string code)
{
    if (code.Contains("end") && code.Length == 4)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Close?", "Close window?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            return "";
        else
            return "Closing closed";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
        return "I don't understand ... ";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) i don't want to use your version of my code but do  : public static void OnCommand(Form1 frm)     ..worked...i will just look to your version and proboblly use it :D :)