# Populate a gridform from another Class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, datagrid

This question is simular to:

-[How to change a label from another class? c# windows forms visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770920/how-to-change-a-label-from-another-class-c-sharp-windows-forms-visual-studio)

However, i didn't find a suitable answer there:

I want to request a gridform to be updated when a method from another class is called.

So far I have this in the same public partial class as the form (the button is temporary).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateNodeForm();
}

public void UpdateNodeForm()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("-----message recieved to update tables-----");
    DataTable nodeTable = new DataTable();
    nodeTable = SqlConnections.GetNodeTableData();
    dataGridViewNodes.DataSource = nodeTable.DefaultView;
}
```

When I click the button the above code works just fine.

When I run the following from another public static class, however, the method is called in a new instance but it doesn't update the form (the form class is called Tables).

```
public static void InsertNode(string node_name, float x, float y, float z_cover)
{        
    //bunch of other stuff here that I've stripped out.

    Tables tables = new Tables();
    Debug.WriteLine("-----send instruction to rebuilt nodes tables-----");
    tables.UpdateNodeForm();
}
```

The above clearly isn't the way I should be doing this.
How can I makke the method UpdateNodeForm(); listen for the InsertNode(); method to be run?

Comment: hmmm...try to set dataGridViewNodes.DataSource = null when you InsertNode..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion muhammadaa but this didn't make any difference.

Comment: For my own learning, I would be grateful if anyone can advise why my question has been marked down. I can't see any obvious issues with the question or how I have weritten it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are creating a new instance of Tables and calling UpdateNodeForm on that.

```
public static void InsertNode(string node_name, float x, float y, float z_cover)
{
    Tables tables = new Tables(); // This creates a new instance of Tables
    tables.UpdateNodeForm(); // This updates the new instance of Tables
}
```

You need to get a reference to the original "Tables" form and call UpdateNodeForm on that, alternately if you are only ever going to have one Tables form then you can update your static InsertNode function to find the existing form and update that.

```
public static void InsertNode(string node_name, float x, float y, float z_cover)
{
    Tables tables = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Tables>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (tables != null)
        tables.UpdateNodeForm();
}
```

What this will do is look in the Application.OpenForms list for Forms that are of type Tables. If there is one it will get a reference to it and call UpdateNodeForm(). If it doesn't exist then it will do nothing.

Edit:
Make sure you are using the following namespace:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: This worked great thank you. I hadn't realised that "Application.OpenForms" even existed (very very new to C#) so thank you for opening up new possibilities.