# Issue with changing Label's text of another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms `Form1` and `Form2`, the `Form1` contains a label called `label1` (public) now that on `Form2` contains a TextBox and a button that supposed to retrieves the input from the TextBox and I was trying to change the text of `label1` from `Form1` form to the input of the TextBox from `Form2`.

Here's what I've tried so far,

`Form1` class:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {  
           InitializeComponent();
           this.Text = "Main Form";
         }


    public void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        
    }

       public void change_label_func(string ss) {
           this.label1.Text = ss;
       }
       
           public void button1_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                  Form4 sec_form = new Form4();
                  sec_form.Show();
}

 }
```

`Form2` class:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Create New Directory Page";
            this.Icon = new Icon(@"C:\Users\USER\Documents\FlowStorage4.ico");

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

       }

        public void guna2Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
         
             Form1 get_dir = new Form1();
             get_dir.change_label_func(textBox2.Text);
       }
```

Now that when I clicked the button, the label on `Form1` makes no changes.

Comment: as you may know, `doesn't work` isn't really a helpful explaination of your problem, could you be more precise.

Comment: little hint, calling `Form1 get_dir = new Form1();` which creates a NEW form isn't really suited to change a value of an OLD form

Comment: Probably answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770920/how-to-change-a-label-from-another-class-c-sharp-windows-forms-visual-studio

Comment: Are those forms in same program? If yes, how are you opening the second form?

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir Yes they're in the same program, I uses `Form4 sec_form = new Form4()` to open the second form.

Comment: @Md. Suman Kabir  Yes, my problem is solved thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your code. you are always using a new instance of `Form1` by this line :

```
Form1 get_dir = new Form1();
```

You need to use the instance of `Form1` from where you are opening `Form2`. To do this, declare a `Form` variable in your `Form2` class like below :

```
Public Form parentFrm = new Form();
```

And when you are opening `Form2` in your `Form1`, send the instance of `Form1` like below :

```
Form4 sec_form = new Form4();
sec_form.parentFrm = this;
```

And then, use this instance in your `guna2Button2_Click` event like below :

```
public void guna2Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
    parentFrm.change_label_func(textBox2.Text);
}
```

I have not tested the code, but that's the one of the concepts to make it works.

Answer (score 1):

Every form has a message loop inside which handles updates when the value changes, this has been like that since the beginning of windows.

So:

A window has a windowprocedure attached to it. A function where all messages pass through. The messages are sent to the function because there is a thread running in an endless loop. (until WM_CLOSE)

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

When you say

```
label1.Text = "new";
```

several messages are sent to the windows message queue and they are handled in order. Eg one message that is sent is WM_PAINT which will handle the redrawing of the pixels that make up the text "new".

So sharing labels between forms is generally not done. The message queue handling of one window can be suspended while you set new text n the other. weird things start to happen.